# =ImportXML using Google Doc on EtherDelta gives Imported Content Is Empty error

Tags: html, xpath, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am trying to extract the text value of the last sell order on EtherDelta for a specific crypto currency.

=IMPORTXML(A4,"//*[@id='trades']/div/table/tbody//*[@class='sell']/text()")

A4 = "https://etherdelta.github.io/#AVT-ETH"

The trades table is the list of buy and sell orders on the right hand side of the screen. I go to the body of the table. Each row has 3 table dimensions the first TD of each row is a class that designates if this is a buy or sell order. The XPath above finds the first instance of a sell order. Gets the node of the first column that has this class and retrieves the text. The text should be the price. On the google sheets side i get this error.

Comment: Based from this [link](https://linktosheets.com/web-scraping-using-importxml-google-spreadsheets/), this formula would work for many sitemap files: `=IMPORTXML(“https://moz.com/blog-sitemap.xml”, “//url/loc”)` but you may encounter an error when a namespace is declared at the beginning of the sitemap so you can’t directly request `//url/loc`. You may also check this [related thread](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/aUCzvZphqEU).